# Why does standalone method from header file needs to be namespace qualified, when class methods do not?

Tags: c++

I've been debugging code that wouldn't link, since the symbol `dev::solidity::CreateEmptyFuncDef` couldn't be found when defined as  `CreateEmptyFuncDef` in ASTUtils.cpp (return type and parameters are omitted).

But why does `CreateEmptyFunc` needs to be qualified by `dev::solidity`, when the defined `LocationFinder` class methods aren't?

I thought that `using dev::solidity` was sufficient, so that namespace qualifiers may be left out?

**ASTUtils.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <libevmasm/SourceLocation.h>
#include <libsolidity/ast/ASTVisitor.h>
#include <string>

namespace dev
{
namespace solidity
{

class LocationFinder: private ASTConstVisitor
{
public:
    LocationFinder(SourceLocation const& _location, std::vector<ASTNode const*> _rootNodes):
        m_rootNodes(_rootNodes), m_location(_location)
    {
    }

    /// @returns the "closest" (in the sense of most-leafward) AST node which is a descendant of
    /// _node and whose source location contains _location.
    ASTNode const* leastUpperBound();

private:
    bool visitNode(ASTNode const& _node);

    std::vector<ASTNode const*> m_rootNodes;
    SourceLocation m_location;
    ASTNode const* m_bestMatch = nullptr;
};

ASTPointer<FunctionDefinition> CreateEmptyFuncDef(const std::string name, const std::string sourcePath);

}
}
```

**ASTUtils.cpp:**

```
#include <libsolidity/ast/ASTUtils.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace dev;
using namespace dev::solidity;



ASTNode const* LocationFinder::leastUpperBound()
{
    m_bestMatch = nullptr;
    for (ASTNode const* rootNode: m_rootNodes)
        rootNode->accept(*this);

    return m_bestMatch;
}

bool LocationFinder::visitNode(const ASTNode& _node)
{
    if (_node.location().contains(m_location))
    {
        m_bestMatch = &_node;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

ASTPointer<FunctionDefinition> dev::solidity::CreateEmptyFuncDef(const string name, const string sourcePath) {
    SourceLocation _loc(0, 0, make_shared<ASTString>(sourcePath));
    ASTPointer<ASTString> _name = make_shared<ASTString>(name);
    Declaration::Visibility _visibility = Declaration::Visibility::Public;
    StateMutability _mutability = StateMutability::NonPayable;
    bool _isConstructor = false;
    ASTPointer<ASTString> _doc = make_shared<ASTString>();
    std::vector<ASTPointer<VariableDeclaration>> _varDecs;
    ASTPointer<ParameterList> _params = make_shared<ParameterList>(_loc, _varDecs);
    std::vector<ASTPointer<ModifierInvocation>> _mods;
    ASTPointer<ParameterList> _retParams = make_shared<ParameterList>(_loc, _varDecs);
    std::vector<ASTPointer<Statement>> _statements; 
    ASTPointer<Block> _body = make_shared<Block>(_loc, _doc, _statements); // empty block
    return make_shared<FunctionDefinition>(_loc, _name, _visibility, _mutability, _isConstructor, _doc, _params, _mods, _retParams, _body); 
}
```

Comment: Surely you know that huge chunks of the code you've provided are completely irrelevant to your question? Why don't you apply the small amount of effort needed to produce a ***minimal*** [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using namespace` directive makes existing name available to current namespace but it doesn't forbid you to define new name, i.e. name that doesn't conflict with existing names. When you do something like this in global namespace:

```
ASTPointer<FunctionDefinition> CreateEmptyFuncDef(const string name, const string sourcePath) {
    //
}
```

It declares and defines a new function `CreateEmptyFuncDef` which is different from previously declared `dev::solidity::CreateEmptyFuncDef`.

To avoid the `dev::solidity::` qualification you can enclose this function inside `dev::solidity` namespace like this:

```
namespace dev {
namespace solidity {

ASTPointer<FunctionDefinition> CreateEmptyFuncDef(const string name, const string sourcePath) {
    //
}

}
}
```

That will define `dev::solidity::CreateEmptyFuncDef` without introducing a new name.

The class name should have been qualified with namespace too. For example, consider the following minimum code:

```
namespace foo {

class Bar {
void baz();
};

}

void Bar::baz() {}

int main() {
}
```

With gcc it fails to compile with error:

```
test.cpp:9:6: error: ‘Bar’ has not been declared
 void Bar::baz() {}
      ^
```

To compile you either need:

```
void foo::Bar::baz() {}
```

Or enclose it inside namespace too.

Comment: Thank you, but why isn't that necessary for class methods?

Comment: Your class should have been qualified with namespace too. Are you sure this is the exact code that you are using?

Comment: Yes, I've haven't made the class myself. I'm just adding a method to ASTUtils.cpp/h - It is the Solidity project for Ethereum.

Comment: Maybe the compiler is smart enough to deduce that the class methods are from the dev::solidity namespace?

Comment: @Shuzheng I don't know whether any compiler can do that. What is your compiler and which extensions are you using?

Comment: I'm just using the newest version of GCC on Ubuntu Linux. Doing a search the class or its methods are not used in source code. However, the code still compiles just fine.

Comment: @Shuzheng no, it doesn't compile with gcc 7.2 either: https://godbolt.org/g/1NLoAS I'm sure something else is going on with your codes.